# How to copy the contents of a balloon notification in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

The following balloon notification / warning was displayed: how can I copy its contents? There is no right click/context menu and I can not highlight the text for copying:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the notifications bar on the left side to see and copy the balloon warnings:

[image]

As you can see here I can copy it from the notification bar:

[image]

Comment: Hope it helps you to copy the warnings.